# How to have a reduced correlation table in R?

Tags: r, correlation

I would like a correlation table only for my two main variables, but with more than ten other parameters. Here is the thing in Python  [table python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KV8O.png).
I would like to do the same thing in R, but I only manage to have a big matrix 12*12. I just want to select 2 variables. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`cor` will create the whole correlation matrix, and you can select the two variables you want to display by indexing their columns.

This is a very basic example.

```r
cor(mtcars)[, c("mpg", "cyl")]
#>             mpg        cyl
#> mpg   1.0000000 -0.8521620
#> cyl  -0.8521620  1.0000000
#> disp -0.8475514  0.9020329
#> hp   -0.7761684  0.8324475
#> drat  0.6811719 -0.6999381
#> wt   -0.8676594  0.7824958
#> qsec  0.4186840 -0.5912421
#> vs    0.6640389 -0.8108118
#> am    0.5998324 -0.5226070
#> gear  0.4802848 -0.4926866
#> carb -0.5509251  0.5269883
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you want to do more manipulation with it, you might want to take an extra step to coerce this matrix to `tibble` with the `rownames` argument so you get those variable names into a column instead of a rowname.

Comment: In fact I would have liked something visual, as the corrplot function allows, but only by presenting 2 variables. The corrplot function returns the whole matrix unfortunately

Comment: OK.  I recommend asking a new question then.  This one has been around for a few days, and the title and first post ask for a table, not a plot.